# PHP fgetcsv array issues with comma delimiting

Tags: php, mysql, fgetcsv

I seem to be having a problem with my fgetcsv command not comma delimiting, basically what is happening is my data is just one really long string in an array.  I need the data to be in an array format for the implode function to work properly for uploading into a mysql database.

Currently the mysql upload looks like...

```
INSERT INTO metars VALUES('PAJZ 011132Z AUTO 1 3/4SM BR FEW009 BKN019 OVC026 08/07 A2959 RMK AO2 PWINO TSNO P0001,PAJZ,2013-07-01T11:32:00Z,59.73,-157.27,8.0,7.0,,,,1.75,29.589567,,,TRUE,TRUE,,,TRUE,,TRUE,BR,FEW,900,BKN,1900,OVC,2600,,,IFR,,,,,,0.01,,,,,,SPECI,82.0"
```

This should have single quotes around each element, however since its a string the implode isn't working =\

```
<?php

require_once("../config/dbmetar.php");

$file = "metars.csv";
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST_METAR, DB_USER_METAR, DB_PASS_METAR, DB_NAME_METAR);
$r = 0;

if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 3000, ",", '"')) !== FALSE) {
        if ($r >= 6) { //skips the header
            foreach($data as $i => $content) {

                $data[$i] = $db->real_escape_string($content);

            }

            //echo "INSERT INTO metars VALUES('" . implode("','", $data) . '"' ;
            //echo var_dump($data);
            $db->query("INSERT INTO metars VALUES('" . implode("','", $data) . "');");

        }
        $r++;   
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

?>
```

Here's an example of the csv file

```
No errors
Max results hit (1000): not all possible results returned; 
59 ms
data source=metars
948 results
raw_text,station_id,observation_time,latitude,longitude,temp_c,dewpoint_c,wind_dir_degrees,wind_speed_kt,wind_gust_kt,visibility_statute_mi,altim_in_hg,sea_level_pressure_mb,corrected,auto,auto_station,maintenance_indicator_on,no_signal,lightning_sensor_off,freezing_rain_sensor_off,present_weather_sensor_off,wx_string,sky_cover,cloud_base_ft_agl,sky_cover,cloud_base_ft_agl,sky_cover,cloud_base_ft_agl,sky_cover,cloud_base_ft_agl,flight_category,three_hr_pressure_tendency_mb,maxT_c,minT_c,maxT24hr_c,minT24hr_c,precip_in,pcp3hr_in,pcp6hr_in,pcp24hr_in,snow_in,vert_vis_ft,metar_type,elevation_m"
"PAJZ 011132Z AUTO 1 3/4SM BR FEW009 BKN019 OVC026 08/07 A2959 RMK AO2 PWINO TSNO P0001,PAJZ,2013-07-01T11:32:00Z,59.73,-157.27,8.0,7.0,,,,1.75,29.589567,,,TRUE,TRUE,,,TRUE,,TRUE,BR,FEW,900,BKN,1900,OVC,2600,,,IFR,,,,,,0.01,,,,,,SPECI,82.0"
"CYOD 011131Z 18002KT 1/2SM FG FEW250 RMK CI0,CYOD,2013-07-01T11:31:00Z,54.4,-110.28,,,180,2,,0.5,,,,,,,,,,,FG,FEW,25000,,,,,,,LIFR,,,,,,,,,,,,SPECI,544.0"
"CYYD 011131Z AUTO VRB06KT 5SM -RA BR FEW007 BKN070 OVC084 15/14 A3005 RMK PRESRR PCPN 1.0MM PAST HR SLP173 DENSITY ALT 1900FT,CYYD,2013-07-01T11:31:00Z,54.82,-127.18,15.0,14.0,0,6,,5.0,30.050198,1017.3,,TRUE,,,,,,,-RA BR,FEW,700,BKN,7000,OVC,8400,,,MVFR,,,,,,,,,,,,SPECI,523.0"
"KNSE 011131Z 00000KT 10SM -RA FEW025 BKN070 BKN120 BKN250 23/19 A2980 RMK AO2 WSHFT 1045 RAB29 P0000 $ ,KNSE,2013-07-01T11:31:00Z,30.72,-87.02,23.0,19.0,0,0,,10.0,29.799213,,,,TRUE,TRUE,,,,,-RA,FEW,2500,BKN,7000,BKN,12000,BKN,25000,VFR,,,,,,0.0050,,,,,,SPECI,61.0"
```

I've been trying to solve this dilemma for about 6 hours with no luck, i've tried different csv pull methods such as str_getcsv, fgetcsv, i've tried both foreach and for... the simplified version is what I have below and is the easiest way for updating header information.

Purpose: this php script will be ran about every 60sec-150sec in a cron scheduler, if you have any other suggestions regarding this, I would appreciate that information as well.

I do appreciate any help in this matter,

Thanks,

-Mikael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider using `file()` for this type of operation so you can trim the first few lines out and trim the quotes off the ends of the CSV string. The `fgetcsv` parameters you passed are for each column to be wrapped in quotes, not the entire string.

From there, you can then use `str_getcsv()`

Example (untested):

```
<?php
$file = file("metars.csv");
for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) array_shift($file);
foreach($file as $line) {
  $line = ltrim($line, '"');
  $line = rtrim($line, '"');
  $csv  = str_getcsv($line);
  /** do query, preferably a prepared statement **/
}
?>
```

Of course, if your file is massive - this may not be the best solution.